# integrity constraint violation 1062 with ORM and Symfony2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, orm, entity

I have an Entity with a primary key like this:

```
 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="product_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id     
 */
protected $productId;

....

/**
 * Set productId
 *
 * @param integer $productId
 * @return Products
 */
public function setProductId($productId)
{
    $this->productId = $productId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get productId
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getProductId()
{
    return $this->productId;
}
```

But when I try to insert an ProductId with set method, I get this error:

> integrity constraint violation 1062 duplicate entry '0' for key 'primary'

I tried with * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE") but the result it's the same, I need to set the Product Id because the sequence isn't 1, 2, 3... is different.

And I can't create a new Id because my current ProductId is used by other entities like Foreing Keys.

Any solution?
Thanks in advance.

-----Edit with the file where I have the error-----

```
$prod = new Products();
$prod->setProductId("65");
$manager->persist($prod);
$manager->flush();
```

----Edit with whole Entity----

namespace My\WebBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

```
class Products
{
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="product_id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="NONE")
 */
protected $productId;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="version", type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $version;

 /**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="code", type="string", length=10, nullable=false)
 */
private $code;

/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="price", type="integer", nullable=false)
 */
private $price;

 /**
 * Set productId
 *
 * @param integer $productId
 * @return Products
 */
public function setProductId($productId)
{
    $this->productId = $productId;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get productId
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getProductId()
{
    return $this->productId;
}    

/**
 * Set name
 *
 * @param string $name
 * @return Products
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get name
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * Set version
 *
 * @param integer $version
 * @return Products
 */
public function setVersion($version)
{
    $this->version = $version;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get version
 *
 * @return integer 
 */
public function getVersion()
{
    return $this->version;
}

/**
 * Set code
 *
 * @param string $code
 * @return Products
 */
public function setCode($code)
{
    $this->code = $code;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get code
 *
 * @return string 
 */
public function getCode()
{
    return $this->code;
}
/**
 * Set price
 *
 * @param integer $price
 * @return Products
 */
public function setPrice($price)
{
    $this->price = $price;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get price
 *
 * @return integer
 */
public function getPrice()
{
    return $this->price;
}
```

Comment: can you post the whole entity? maybe there is an error in your annotations?

Comment: Ok my test with v2.4.2 of Doctrine doesn't throw any exception. Which version are you using? Sorry, i've no clue what's happening in your environment...

Answer (score 1):

When using no identifier generation strategy you should not forget that you have to assign the custom ID **before** you call EntityManagers persist() method.

I think you are persisting the new Entity before assigning the custom ID which means your $productId property is set to null and will be casted to 0 (zero) if you try to flush it. That will cause your error.

[Doctrine Doc](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#identifier-generation-strategies)

Comment: Thanks, but I do this right, I think. See my edit code at the end of my first question. Thanks

Comment: Yes, I just wrote in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Marcus post a good answer to your problem. You can solve it by adding id into you Entity, and use productId as secondary key.

Add id and set it to Auto increment, like

```
/**
* @ORM\Column(type="integer")
* @ORM\Id
* @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
*/
protected $id;
```

Then you can use your productId with:

```
 /**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="product_id", type="integer", nullable=false)    
 */
protected $productId;
```

With this solution you will use $productId as secondary key. Don't forget to clear data in your table.

You also have an error here:

```
$prod->setProductId(65);
```

Now you try set data which is string - in your table is integer.

Comment: Thanks. The 2nd with the error, really I haven't the error, I use $prod->setProductId($var); and this $var is a integer. As for your answer thanks a lot, but one question, I use this Primary Key (productId) like foreing key in another table, so if I do your answer, when I update my databases I get an error that said me about this primary key can't change because is used by other tables like foreing key. Thanks.

Comment: Drop the tables manually (in phpmyadmin for example) that are related with this error and create it again.

Comment: When I drop the table said: "Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails, 1217" :/

Comment: Try to drop tables one by one - first the tables that have foreign keys. It should work.

Comment: Well i think this could work but it is just a workaround to a problem that should not exist. i tried exactly the same (no generation strategy) and it is working well. adding another pKey column  will only add "useless" overhead to the table, because the product id will be the better choice for the primary key column.